# Why do I need to estimate factor scores rather than simply derive them?

Tags: factor-analysis

It seems to be a well-known fact, but I never got why. I want to know, why factor scores are estimated, or respectively where my mistake in the rearrangement below lies. Admittedly, matrix algebra has never been a strengh of mine but I could not find a contradiction yet.

Let's assume that I've estimated my loading matrix and thereby also the specific factors. I kept fewer factors $k$ than original variables $q$.

My nomenclature is:

$X$ are the manifest variables of dim: $q\times 1$

$L$ is the loading matrix $q\times k$

$F$ are the factors $k\times 1$

$E$ are the specific factors $q\times 1$

The basic model for factor analysis is as follows:

$X=LF+E$

Here my rearrangement steps:

1. $X-E=LF$
2. $X^{*}=LF$
3. $L'X^{*}=L'LF$
4. $(L'L)^{-1}L'X^{*}=F$ (assuming $(L'L)$ being non-singular).

I know $X$, I know $L$, what I don't know is why this is not permissible.

Comment: Here is what you seem to be overlooking: how do you obtain $E$ (which you need to use on your step #2)?

Comment: I assume my manifest variables standardized. Then E obtains as 1 minus the sum of squared loadings.

Comment: This seems only to be true in PCA, but does not have to be true in factor analysis in general. In general, in factor analysis you estimate loadings and uniquenesses, which are variances of individual terms in $E$ over $n$ samples. But you can't go from uniquenesses to elements of $E$ without some "estimating" process. In PCA the scores don't need to be "estimated", they can be unambiguously computed, that's true. But PCA is not FA.

Comment: I was supposing that the problems lies therein. ;-) But if I don't have $E$, what are calculated uniquenesses I have? I mean, at the beginning of a factor analysis, that is, when I try to find an estimate for the loadings, I often start with an estimate of $E$, right? But that must be a different one, I guess.

Comment: No, you don't start with an estimate of $E$. You start with an estimate of variances of elements of $E$ over your $n$ samples. They are called uniquenesses (usually notated as $\Psi$). So when you fit a factor analysis model, you only estimate the error *variances*, not the error terms themselves.

Comment: @amoeba, you might think about posting an answer to this good question, because you actually answered it already. (In the answer, you could collect some links over the topic, including those to your own and my answers.)

Comment: @D.Stroet, `I know X`. But you don't know $X^*$. Where do you think to get it?